# Custom Fonts With Windows Azure

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, azure, fonts

I am having the hardest time right now. I have an application that looks GORGEOUS in Visual Studio however the moment I publish to Windows Azure the custom fonts just do not show up and make the application look terrible. I use custom fonts and custom Icons that are loaded from the fonts. Bootstrapv3 and others that I have used.

I have done lots of research, found a lot of solutions all pointing to the same thing and I am still having issues here is what I have done:

Anyways I made sure that all the font files are set to Content in the Build action and that still didnt fix it.

I updated the Web.config to include the following:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
  <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

The website is [AZURE WEBSITE LINK](http://bigdaddypools.azurewebsites.net)

I still have no idea how to get the custom fonts to work. If you look at the link the text "Sign in to Big Daddy Pools" is actually a customized font but looks BLAH... Please help I have spent days on this!

Comment: Are you actually getting the file? Does it exist when requesting it directly from the server? Is RAMMFAR doing something with the request?

Comment: If I actually enter the full Font path yes I can download the file. What do you mean by RAMMFAR

Comment: Ok then it's probably not RAMMFAR (runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests) if you can download the file. If you check your browser's developer tools and look at the requests being made, can you verify the file is actually being requested and downloaded?

Comment: Did you try restarting your site after deployment? I had the same issue and restart have fixed it.

Comment: I tried to restart it just now and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS file has this at the top:

`/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(2412,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@import'
(2412,9): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found 'url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700)'
 */`

You might want to fix that first as when I load the page you've provided above I don't see any network requests outbound from the browser to request these font files.